# Whatsapi PHP Internal server error

Tags: php, whatsapp, whatsapi

I'm trying to use Whatsapi for PHP but it's not working while I call the loginWithPassword function.
My code:

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__.'/src/whatsprot.class.php';
require_once __DIR__.'/src/events/MyEvents.php';

$username = 'Number';
$password = 'Password';
$nickname = 'Nick';
$target = "targetNumber";
$debug = true;  

$w = new WhatsProt($username, $nickname, $debug);
$events = new MyEvents($w);
$events->setEventsToListenFor($events->activeEvents);

$w->connect();
$w->loginWithPassword($password);
$w->sendMessage($target, 'Guess the number :)');
$w->sendMessage($target, 'Sent from RopajiBotServices at '.date('H:i'));
?>
```

This is the message I receive:

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator,
>   webmaster@basededatostoons.com and inform them of the time the error
>   occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the
>   error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to
>   use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Thanks

Comment: The cause will be something outside of the code you have provided. Do you have access to the server logs?

Comment: Yes, but I only have access logs :(

Comment: I'd advise breaking it down line by line and adding `error_reporting(E_ALL)` at the start

Comment: Same message :(